# how to disable cart functionality from woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to disable cart functionality from woocommerce store. I want user can only see products available.customer can not purchase from store.

Answer (score 15):

the easiest way is make the products not purchasable..

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable','__return_false',10,2);
```

Answer (score 5):

To fully disable woocommerce purchase functionality:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false'); // DISABLING PURCHASE FUNCTIONALITY AND REMOVING ADD TO CART BUTTON FROM NORMAL PRODUCTS

remove_action('woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10); // REMOVING PRICE FROM VARIATIONS

remove_action('woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20); // REMOVING ADD TO CART BUTTON FROM VARIATIONS
```

More option you can find here: https://react2wp.com/remove-hide-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-while-disabling-keeping-purchase-functionality/

Comment: This answer is wrong. `add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');` is enough.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson You are actually incorrect. That wouldn't be enough. There is a reason why I added the remove_actionns.

Comment: This answer is actually right, I tried only the first line and it only disables the "Add to cart" button, but still shows it. Adding the additional lines completely dissapears the button.

Answer (score 1):

If you need conditions, you can use the following code:

```
function m3wc_woocommerce_is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    // Conditions here.

    return $is_purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'm3wc_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```

For example, if you need to check users:

```
// Disable purchase for non-logged-in users.
function m3wc_woocommerce_is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $is_purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'm3wc_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```