# Disable just the checkout option in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, checkout, disable

I have a WordPress shopping site. for the time being I want to just disable the checkout option from my site until I update all the price of the products. I tried searching over net for different solutions. but could not find any suitable solution. I am expecting to get help from here. thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to disable cart functionality from woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314168/how-to-disable-cart-functionality-from-woocommerce)

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout',
'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);
```

Comment: Tried this solution. but it did not work. but thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable all the payment options at WooCommerce->Settings page. That should refrain user from completing the order until you done with your price update.

Update:
If you want to entirely remove the button from the view, then you may need to modify the WooCommerce file. Edit the below files:

path: /woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php

```
//search woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout and comment the line
//this will remove the button from cart page

<?php //do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' ); ?>
```

path: /woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php

```
//search woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout and comment the line
//this will remove the checkout on the cart menu display

//echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ) . '" class="button checkout wc-forward">' . esc_html__( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
```

Comment: I have disabled all the payment options. but the problem is even after disabling the payment options it still displays the checkout button which I don't want. I want the checkout button to completely disappear until I turn it back on.